# how to set dynamic Where Clause in Linq Query with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:-

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

String s = "StudentID = 5 Or StudentID=6"; 
var result = from r in ds.table[0].AsEnumerable() where s.ToString() select r;
```

How to get data from this?

Comment: If you need LINQ and this is just an example then you should use Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: Often you can do this with composition of many small static clauses. Why do you need to use dynamic where clauses?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use a list of ID's?

```
//assuming you have text and that's the reason
var txtIDs = "5,6";
var IDs = txtIDs.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s));

var rows = from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
           where IDs.Any(id => r.Field<int>("ID")==id)
           select r;
```

or in method syntax:

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => IDs.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row["StudentID"].ToString() == "5" || row["StudentID"].ToString() == "6")
```

or

```
var result = from r in dx.AsEnumerable() 
             where r["StudentID"].ToString() == "5" || r["StudentID"].ToString() == "6" 
             select r;
```

You can try this

```
DataTable dt = result.CopyToDataTable(); //for both code above
```

Comment: Thank you to all But I want to fire my Own Select query to Linq and he will return table data to me. ???